# What are the constant values used in generating pseudo random number in java.util.Random?

Tags: java, random

I am a little curious what are the constant values (if they even are truly 
constant) used in `java.util.Random`.

I used the method `setSeed()` and give it a value of `3` and set the limit of the value it can generate to `5` or `random.nextInt(5)`.

```
random.setSeed(3);
int[] n = new int[5];
for(int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    n[i] = random.nextInt(5);
}
```

The numbers generated are `4, 0, 0, 1, 3`. I know that the `java.util.Random` uses the linear congruential number generator to generate random numbers.

X<sub>n+1</sub> = (*a*X<sub>*n*</sub> + c) mod *m*

Now, how can I trace back or find the values used in the linear number congruential generator. I know that the X<sub>*n*</sub> value is the seed value I put, which is in this case is `3`. How can I find the value of *m*, *a*, and the c?

Comment: Err, by reading the soruce code?

Comment: `nextInt()` is not the same as `next(int)`

Answer (score 3):

If you look at `java.util.Random` source code you will find:

```
private static final long multiplier = 0x5DEECE66DL;
private static final long addend = 0xBL;
private static final long mask = (1L << 48) - 1;
```

and the logic for generating a random value is in `next(int)` method:

```
protected int next(int bits) {
    long oldseed, nextseed;
    AtomicLong seed = this.seed;
    do {
        oldseed = seed.get();
        nextseed = (oldseed * multiplier + addend) & mask;
    } while (!seed.compareAndSet(oldseed, nextseed));
    return (int)(nextseed >>> (48 - bits));
}
```

Comment: Ok so the `a` is equal to `0x5DEECE66DL` and the `c` equal to `0xBL` . To be honest, I am still a beginner and I still don't know many things in programming. So what do those values means if it becomes an int?

Answer (score 2):

In reference to the formula you posted:

X<sub>n+1</sub> = (aX<sub>n</sub> + c) mod m

```
random.setSeed(3);
```

is equivalent to setting X<sub>0</sub> to 3

and

```
random.nextInt(5)
```

is equivalent to executing the formula with m = 5.

The values for a and C can be found by lookinng through the java library source code. To do this right click on your Random and choose view source in your IDE.

Comment: sorry i missed that part, i just added how to find the current values while you were asking. NB: it is possible, although not common, that a and C might change from one release to another - so best to poke around in the source.

Comment: Ok so the a is equal to 0x5DEECE66DL and the c equal to 0xBL . To be honest, I am still a beginner and I still don't know many things in programming. So what do those values means if it becomes an int?

Comment: @robert They are hexadecimal representations of Long numbers. The L at the end is to indicate it's a Long, the rest can be converted to decimal using a hexadecimal converter like: https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html. So a = 25214903917 and c = 11

Comment: @Rick ok so I calculated it `(25214903917 * 3 + 11) mod 5 = 2` . Why is it 2? from my output in which I set the seed at 3 the first number generated is 4. What's my error here?

Comment: "`random.nextInt(5)` is equivalent to executing the formula with m = 5": no, you're thinking of `next(5)`. `nextInt()` calls `next(31)` and then adjusts the result to ensure a uniform distribution.

Comment: @guest so you're saying the value of m is not 5? Then, what is it?

Comment: @robert: 31. This is the difference between `next(int)` and `nextInt(int)`, as I commented on the original question.

Comment: The difference between ```next(int)``` and ```nextInt(int)``` is how the function treats the value passed to it. You can read more about it here [next](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#next-int-) and [nextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-). Basically nextInt uses the parameter (lets call it N) to return a value between such that 0 <= Value < N. So the N is effectively the modulus value in the equation.

Comment: The other function ```next(int)``` interprets the parameter as the number of bits to apply to alter the returned value by shifting the random number (X<sub>n+1</sub) to the right using a logical right shift operation (the `>>>` but supplied in the other answer).

Comment: *... is equivalent to setting X0 to 3*. Similar, but not equivalent. *... is equivalent to executing the formula with m = 5*. Again, similar but not equivalent.

Comment: Actually @James_K_Polk if you read the javadoc for nextInt (which is what the OP asked about), you will see the following ```public int nextInt(int bound) {``` ... ```val = bits % bound;``` and finally ```return val;```. I've omitted bits due to the limited format in a comment. Given the parameter (i.e. bound) is used in the modulos to calculate the return val, I would propose that they are more than equivalent. I suspect any confusion might lie in that the other answer referenced the code ```next(int)``` which the OP did not actually ask about (they asked about nextInt(int).